# Rails tokenized text search across fields with performance in mind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, full-text-search

I have a Rails app on Heroku that I'm looking to increase the user-friendlyness of the search for. To do this, I'd like to allow them to text search across multiple fields on multiple models through associations. The input from the user could be a mix of text from any of these fields (and often might span multiple fields) in no particular order.

Example: if you had a car database and wanted to allow the user to search "Honda Fit 2011", where "Honda" came from the manufacturer table, "Fit" came from the model table, and "2011" came from the model_year table.

I'm thinking that I need to build a single field on the root record that contains the unique list of words from each of these fields, and then tokenize the user's input. But that would cause me to use an `IN` clause, which I'm not sure could benefit from full-text search plugins like [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search).

So, my question is what's a good way to active a search like this in Rails?

Comment: A fulltext search over all models doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: full text search is usually a task you give to external tool. you might want to look at solr/lucene, sphinx or elastic search.

Comment: @Tass the full-text across multiple models, if I'm not mistaken, would always return the items from the different tables. I probably wasn't clear: in my car example I'd always want to return the model_year records. So a search for "honda" would bring back all of the model_years that through associations can be tracked back to the "honda" manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Sunspot_rails.  It uses Solr as it's search engine, but allows you index content in all sorts of fruity ways.  For instance, I have models indexed with their associations pretty simply:

```
searchable do
  text :description
  text :category do
    category.present? ? category.name : ''
  end
end
```

You can then search with:

```
TYPES = [Asset,Product]

Sunspot.search(*TYPES) do |q|
  q.fulltext search_str
end
```